# How To Hide a div based on value in inner div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jtable

```
<form id="jtable-edit-form" class="jtable-dialog-form jtable-edit-form">
<div class="jtable-input-field-container">
    <div class="jtable-input-label">Type</div>
    <div class="jtable-input jtable-text-input">
        <input class="" id="Edit-configType" type="text" name="configType">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="jtable-input-field-container">
    <div class="jtable-input-label">Key</div>
    <div class="jtable-input jtable-text-input">
        <input class="" id="Edit-configKey" type="text" name="configKey">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="jtable-input-field-container">
    <div class="jtable-input-label">Value</div>
    <div class="jtable-input jtable-text-input">
        <input class="" id="Edit-configValue" type="text" name="configValue">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="jtable-input-field-container">
    <div class="jtable-input-label">Description</div>
    <div class="jtable-input jtable-text-input">
        <input class="" id="Edit-description" type="text" name="description">
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to hide 1 div out of 4 div. I want to hide only div which has inner div as value 'Key'.

Please note that I am not allowed to changed HTML content. I can just write Jquery for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
$("#jtable-edit-form .jtable-input-label:contains('Key')" ).parent().hide();
```

See this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cL4wsL3q/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$( "div.jtable-input-label:contains('Key')" )
    .closest( "div.jtable-input-field-container" )
    .css( "display", "none" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Because IDs must be unique on document context, you should target specific parent element containing `#Edit-configKey` DIV instead:

```
$('#Edit-configKey').closest('.jtable-input-field-container').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $( "div.jtable-input-label:contains('Key')" ).parent().hide();
});
```

Hope this will help you.